# Is there anything available to 'Escape' Key press or click on 'Cancel' button for upload file in C# with selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[image: Would lic]ke to click on Cancel or Escape by keyboard to close this file upload window for c# with selnium]

I tried following thing to close this in my code

> I tried with following code but it is not working

created object of Actions class :

```
  Actions a = new Actions(driver);
     a.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Escape);
     System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");
     a.SendKeys(Keys.Escape).Build().Perform();
```

> i also tried to use Tab key press to reach cancel button but nothing is work there.

I would like to closed this file upload window by Escape or click on cancel button on file upload window. Any java script available for this. please let me know.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/53940857/10413416 hope it helps, you dont need to interact with OS file select window to upload a file using selenium.

Comment: @Infern0 , in my case there is "Upload" button and after click on that file upload window has been open and by using line ( Driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement().SendKeys(String fileName); document's content pasted in text area but file upload window has been remain open.There is no input text box for file path.

Comment: Paste html sample, there should be an input near the button or at the bottom of body.

Comment: @Infern0 , you are right thanks alot. i inspected and found input which previously i thought for button but it works as you said. i made xpath and use sendkeys and it works. <input id="resumeUploadInput" class="fileUpload-realButton" type="file" name="file"> . this is a line which i thought as a button. without inract with os we can do that this way. thanks :)